# How to Start an AppCompatActivity from a non AppCompatActivity Class?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

[Classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnRi5.png)

Let's say I have my main activity A that is a AppCompactActivity, I want in this class A (for example in OnCrete) to do:

```
new B().show();
```

Class B would have a method show like :

```
private void show(){
   Intent c = new Intent(A.this, C.class);
   startActivity(c);
}
```

How can I make this work?

I tried to do the implementation above.

Comment: Removed `android-studio` tag as that tag is for questions/issues related to the Android Studio product. Your question has nothing to do with Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to add a parameter to the `show()` method passing a reference to the activity A:

```
new B().show(myActivityA);


private void show(AppCompactActivity myActivityA){
   Intent c = new Intent(A.this, C.class);
   myActivityA.startActivity(c);
}
```

Comment: @Gino you probably want `myActivityA` instead of `A.this`.